# may i know the difference between [cultureinfo]::InstalledUICulture and get-uiculture in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, azure-powershell

may i know the difference between [cultureinfo]::InstalledUICulture and get-uiculture in powershell?

i tried [cultureinfo]::InstalledUICulture in windows 10 and works well but not in windows 7. so i got command get-uiculture in powershell but not sure if it gives same result as [cultureinfo]::InstalledUICulture.

Answer (score 0):

Cultures are a little weird honestly, You can View the source code for `Get-UICulture` [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/c1faf1e6e10fc1ce45e84ef6f49ae7136c67a111/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/GetUICultureCommand.cs)

the command simply returns the value of `$host.CurrentUICulture` which can be different from `$host.CurrentCulture`

on my system currently I get the following:

```
Write-Host "Current Culture: $((Get-Culture).Name)"
Write-Host "Current UI Culture: $((Get-UICulture).Name)"
Current Culture: en-IE
Current UI Culture: en-US
```

for `[CultureInfo]::InstalledUICulture` you can see the difference between it and `[CultureInfo]::UICulture` : [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
CurrentCulture
```

> Gets or sets the CultureInfo object that represents the culture used by the current thread.

```
CurrentUICulture
```

> Gets or sets the CultureInfo object that represents the current user interface culture used by the Resource Manager to look up culture-specific resources at run time.

```
InstalledUICulture
```

> Gets the CultureInfo that represents the culture installed with the operating system.

hopefully that clears it up a little for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running WMF 5.1 on Windows 7, but the only difference that I see is that `[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InstalledUICulture` has `IsReadOnly` set to `$true`, while `Get-UICulture` has `IsReadOnly` set to `$false`.

That means it's like the difference between these:

```
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::New('en-US')
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::ReadOnly([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::New('en-US'))
```

Or:

```
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::New([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InstalledUICulture)
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::ReadOnly([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InstalledUICulture)
```

Looking internally, however, it looks like `Get-UICulture` is a rather pointless command. All it really does is return `(Get-Host).CurrentUICulture` or `$host.CurrentUICulture`, both of which have `IsReadOnly` set to `$false`.